# Converting API call into List of Dictionaries to Write to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, http, decode, urllib

I am calling an API and it's returning a list of dictionaries, but in bytes type. I tried decoding, but wound up with a string instead of a list of dictionaries. I am unsure how to decode this and have the list of dictionaries back to then be able to write to a dataframe or CSV.

My code looks like this (I hid the subscription key):

```
headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '***',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
})

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.fantasydata.net')
    conn.request("GET", "/nascar/v2/json/drivers?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

The output was this (shortened):

```
b'[{
"DriverID":80000544,
"FirstName":"Jeffrey",
"LastName":"Abbey",
"Number":34,
"Team":null,
"BirthDate":null,
"BirthPlace":null,
"Gender":null,
"Height":null,
"Weight":null,
"Manufacturer":null,
"Engine":null,
"Chassis":null,
"Sponsors":null,
"CrewChief":null,
"PhotoUrl":"https:\\/\\/s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\\/static.fantasydata.com\\/headshots\\/nas\\/low-res\\/0.png",
"Updated":"2018-07-14T03:17:41",
"Created":"2017-07-15T09:38:41"}, ...
```

Comment: Use `json` module, `json.loads(data)` or `json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))`. Note: `requests` module provides this automatically on the `response` object.

Comment: Thanks. Where in the code should I put this?

Comment: Somewhere after `data = response.read()` and before the end of the program.